# Receive POST data from login on page, but form action goes to other page

Tags: php, forms, email, post, input-field

Currently I have a login script with a form that goes login.php, on this page the user can login, and the server checks his/her email & password combination.

Now I have another page were users can enter a other form, called employees.php, in this page there is called a input field email, which is to disabled so users can only call them selves sick.

```
<form  class="form" action="absent.php" method="get">

<p class="text">Email:</p>
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $email?>" disabled required>

<p class="text">Reason:</p>
<textarea style="width: 350px" maxlength="100" name="reason" required></textarea>

<p class="text">Date:</p>
<input type="date" name="date" required value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" / min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">          

<br><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">

<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email?>" />
```

This works good, the only problem that I am currently struggling with is that I can't make it work that the Email is connected to the users login email.

```
session_start();


if( isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $email = 'placeholder@test.com';
}

else {
    header("Location: nologin.php");
}
```

This is the code I am using at the top of employees.php.

And this is the form code I am using at login.php.

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">

<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
<input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password" required>

<input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

So how can I make it to work that when a user logs in with his/her account, the email address is automatically filled in, in a not editable inputfield at employees.php?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is a tad confusing, are you having trouble displaying the users email?

Comment: Yes, i am not able to receive the email post data from login.php at employees.php

Comment: @Jummy01234 if you want the `login.php` form to send to `employees.php`, you need to set the action of the login form to `employees.php`.

Comment: @MattCowley, the problem is that the form `login.php` also checks if the user has logged in correctly. So when I set the form action the `employees.php` it says that the user is not logged in. Because that gets checked at `login.php`

Comment: @Jummy01234 In that case you'll need to get the login.php script to redirect the user to the employees.php page after, but you'll have to use a URL variable, because I don't think you can do POST calls in PHP direct (I may be wrong).

Comment: @MattCowley with "curl" u actually can "POST" to a Location. thats usefull for scripts where u have to Login.

Comment: @Jummy01234 remember u have to use `session_start` in every script u want to use $_SESSION.

Comment: @Jummy01234 so to clear Things. u got 1 MASK wherethey can insert the absent of users. if u are logged in u get to page u want. and if not it Fails or what ? just send all to employees.php and if there is no Login just include it. there are many different ways. u can send all data to Login.php and if the session is ok u can curl to employee.php if not u can log him in and then use the data from $post to try the same again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to grab the email from the database first and save it as a session variable. e.g

```
<?php

    require_once 'inc/config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) { //if the login button was clicked

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $selUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login ='${login}' AND password = '${password}'";
        $runUser = mysqli_query($conn, $selUser);
        $checkUser = mysqli_num_rows($runUser);
while($row = $runUser) {
 $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email']; //grabs the email from the database and stores it in a session variable
}
        if($checkUser > 0) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $username;
            echo "<script>window.open('employee.php?login=1','_self')</script>";

}

else {

    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
    header("Location: login.php?err=1");

    }

}

?>
```

the other script will look like this

```
<?php
session_start();


if( isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
}

else {
    header("Location: nologin.php");
}
?>
```